# What are the command line options for an install4j generated uninstaller

Tags: install4j

I've discovered the -q option works on Linux to invoke unattended mode -- There are no prompts for user input, progress is shown, and it waits for completion.  The behavior is different on windows, where it shows no prompts, but does not show progress, and does not wait for completion.  How do I achieve the equivalent results on windows?

For my installer I use the DOS command "start /wait i4jgeninstall -q -splash" which pops up a panel showing progress (no questions) and waits for completion.  Is it possible to do this for an uninstaller on Windows?  I'm using install4j version 5.1.6.

Thanks

Comment: With "start /wait uninstall.exe -q -splash" there indeed is a wait for completion, but no splash screen is shown.  With "start /wait uninstall.exe -q -c" progress is shown in the DOS window.  Is there a configuration option I should be using when I generate the installer to force a splash screen?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the uninstaller is a GUI application. When calling it from the command line, the only way to make it wait for completion is to call it with "start /wait" and the -splash argument, just like you do it for the installer.